# What are anti-sweat technologies in winter jackets called?

Tags: clothing, winter

Once I saw a winter jacket of my roommate with some lining under it. This lining absorbed almost all his sweat, besides logo on his shirt. I searched for it, but cannot find any.

How this linings called? What technologies/cloth used in it. Can I buy some without jacket?

I'm wondering, because I also have a little bit sweating problem. I walk fast and because of it I sweat a lot.

Comment: There is no "one fits all" fabric for that. Every brand has a variation with a different name. You might get better (any) answers if you can dig up the brand of your friends jacket

Comment: @cobaltduck definitely! Also I thought about absorbent fabrics. Idk brand name.

Comment: @user2171669 you don't want the fabric to be absorbent, because that would mean the moisture stays trapped in the fabric. Cotton, for example, is very absorbent. (and you don't want cotton next to your skin in winter)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the comments, it seems that you are looking for some sort of fabric that has [moisture wicking](http://health.howstuffworks.com/wellness/men/sweating-odor/clothing-materials-reduce-sweating.htm) capabilities.  There are several fabrics that have this desirable trait.  Many of them are synthetic blends, and modern chemical engineering is constantly improving the state-of-the-art in moisture wicking fabric.

As to the other part of your question, the answer is definitely yes.  You can get practically any garment- underwear, socks, hats, shirts, pants, shirts, jackets, ... - made using one of these fabrics.  The price points are typically higher than standard fabrics, but some are reasonable as well.  From here, I'll leave it to you to shop for exactly what you want.

EDIT: As an after-thought, note that there is a difference between absorbing and wicking.  A fabric that absorbs pulls sweat **into** itself, and holds it.  A fabric that wicks pulls sweat **through** itself, from wetter areas to drier areas.  Absorbing is usually bad- it leaves you feeling wet and sticky.  In cold times, that wetness degrades any insulating properties of the fabric, and it hot times it slows evaporation, negating your body's natural attempt to cool itself through sweating.  Wicking is preferred, as it moves the sweat away from the body and allows it to evaporate on the outer surface.

Answer (score 3):

paraphasing slightly:

> What are anti-sweat technologies in winter jackets

The best way to prevent sweat in a winter jacket is to use a breathable layering system.

### Base Layer

Tight fitting wicking material that sits close to your skin. The layers job is to wick the moisture off your skin ASAP. Several good materials for this depending on your circumstances mostly polyester or wool. **Do not use cotton!** Cotton does not wick well.

### Breathable insulation layer(s)

Your insulation layers are there to keep you warm. If they get wet though they aren't going to be able to do this effectivly. So once the base layer has removed sweat from your skin it need to get out of your system. Good example of this is a breathable fleece. Multiple layers can be worn depending on how cold it is and you can alter the number of layers depending on how much work your doing.

### Breathable Water proof layer

Something like GoreTex or it's equivalents.

---

Because each layer breaths you don't get wet. The moisture is taken off you skin ASAP and is then slowly released though your layers. It's important to have at least one or two breathable layers next to your skin (if not breathable all the way though) as keeping moisture off your skin will prevent you from getting cold.

> This lining absorbed almost all his sweat

I doubt it... A person can produce a lot of sweat. It's more likely that the lining wiked it off his skin and it was then released into the atmosphere, as above.